# How to kick special or coloured names in Xonotic

Tags: pc, xonotic

I have looked on the FAQ and saw about the "status" command, it is very unclear. I spent an hour trying to find this out and this is my last resort. Has anyone got a clue to kick coloured / special names in Xonotic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to execute `status` or `status 1` command. You can do this on client or on server (in that case you will be able to see client IPs). Result will have `no` column with numbers prefixed with `#`.

Then you can use this number in different commands, like: `vcall kick #2`, `rcon kickban #2`, `rcon kick # 2` instead of player's nick. Actually this number could be used almost in any command instead of nick. There is only one exception: `kick` command. Most commands that accept this number implemented in [QuakeC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuakeC) and accept in this format — `#id`, but `kick` command is implemented in C and part of [engine code](https://github.com/xonotic/darkplaces/blob/master/host_cmd.c#L2059) and it accepts id in this format — `# id` (note space betwee `#` and players id number).

For example, you can send private message to player using `tell <nick>` or `tell #id`. Also, this id have special meaning for game's engine and can be used with debugging commands like **prvm_edictget**, but in that case it should be written without `#`. For example to get players location: `rcon prvm_edictget server 1 origin`. In that case it's written